# don't understand this warning in cuda related to array of structs in _shared_ memory

Tags: cuda

My code runs fine but I don't understand this warning.

**warning: *shared* memory variable with non-empty constructor or deconstructor (potential race between threads)**

I have a struct called facet_cuda

```
struct facet_cuda {
IS_Vector_cuda v[3];
IS_Vector_cuda normal;
double z; };
```

`IS_Vector_cuda` is a class with a default constructor.

Inside global function I am creating an array of facets in shared memory to be filled by every thread in a block

```
__shared__ facet_cuda Faces[BlockSize];
```

Not sure what potential race condition could occur.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The race condition comes about because you have declared an array of the `struct facet_cuda`.

In C++, whenever you declare an array of a class, the [default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) is called to initialise all the elements of that array. The default constructor isn't an empty function. The compiler is issuing a warning because it isn't defined in the CUDA model how shared memory should be initialised (ie. which thread or threads should actually run the constructor to set the values). You should be able to get around this by defining an empty constructor for the device, something like

```
struct facet_cuda {
   IS_Vector_cuda v[3];
   IS_Vector_cuda normal;
   double z; 
   __device__ facet_cuda() {};
};
```

The compiler should optimise the constructor away and the warning should disappear (note totally untested...).

Comment: With C++11 the default constructor declaration is better with `= default;`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the note about constructors [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-qualifiers).

Constructors implicit in device code for global (i.e. `__device__`) or `__shared__` memory variables (which are of a scope that spans more than one thread, by definition) give rise to the question: Who (which thread or threads) will run the constructor?  If multiple threads can run the constructor, then a race condition could arise.